# Ajax keeps getting error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

this is my ajax code and im using Codeigniter framework, and im trying to send data to the controller

```
<script>
    $('#mssgg').submit(function(){
        var ms = $('#mess').val();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'http://localhost/index.php/C_Main_page/store_chat',
            data:'messege'+ms,
            error:function(data){
                alert("error");
            },
            success:function(data){
                alert("success");
            }
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

i keep getting error, what did i do wrong??

Comment: What error you are getting

Comment: use  url:'http://localhost/C_Main_page/store_chat

Comment: check your url..if it is correct

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to stop the form submission because it refreshes the page so motive of ajax ends.
2. You should pass an object although you have a wrong data string to pass `data:'messege'+ms,`.

---

This: `data:'messege'+ms,` either should be `data:'messege='+ms,` or better one as an object `data:{messege:ms},`.

---

```
<script>
    $('#mssgg').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // <----stop the form submission.
        var ms = {messege : $('#mess').val() }; //<----create an object
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'http://localhost/index.php/C_Main_page/store_chat',
            data:ms, //<----and pass that object here.
            error:function(data){
                alert("error");
            },
            success:function(data){
                alert("success");
            }
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
```